# Upload image file to server, store name in MySQL DB

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a file upload only my current script doesn't seem to work as I believe it should.

I've managed to get the data saved in the MySQL table okay but I can't seem to get the file into the 'uploads' directory?

```
if(isset($_POST['new']) && $_POST['new']==1){

    $folder = "uploads/";
    $upload_image = $folder . basename($_FILES["image1"]["name"]);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $upload_image);


    $trn_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $brand =$_REQUEST['brand'];
    $user =$_SESSION["username"];
    $model = $_REQUEST['model'];
    $serial =$_REQUEST['serial'];
    $purchasedate = $_REQUEST['purchasedate'];
    $img1 =$_REQUEST['image1'];
    $ins_query="insert into table
    (`user`,`trn_date`,`brand`,`model`,`serial`,`purchasedate`,`image1`)values
    ('$user','$trn_date','$brand','$model','$serial','$purchasedate','$img1')";
    mysqli_query($con,$ins_query)
    or die(mysql_error());
    $status = "added successfully.
    </br></br><a href='home.php'>home</a>";
}
```

Comment: what is your file name image1 or fileToUpload

Comment: do you have permission to write on `uploads/` ?

Comment: Yes @4givN, it is 755 i think

Comment: It's image1 @VishnuBhadoriya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$upload_image = $folder . basename($_FILES["image1"]["name"]);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image1"]["tmp_name"], $upload_image);
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to move my files

Comment: +1 - although it still leaves the backdoor for code injection wide open. @Liam, if this is not working then either you've not understood how to paste it into your existing code or there is another error you've not told us about.

Comment: check at your form, did you give a correct name for the file input element. And also did you set `enctype= multipart/form-data` option for your form

Answer (score 0):

What if trying directly what the [doc](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.move-uploaded-file.php) said ;)

```
$uploads_dir = '/uploads';//try over 'uploads' too or create a 'uploads' folder in you app_root
foreach ($_FILES["image1"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
    if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $tmp_name = $_FILES["image1"]["tmp_name"][$key];
        $name = $_FILES["image1"]["name"][$key];
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$name");
    }
}
```

Comment: and make sure you replace the `fileToUpload` by `image1`

Answer (score -1):

Possible [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17153624/using-php-to-upload-file-and-add-the-path-to-mysql-database)

I have found an issue in your code.

```
$folder = "uploads/";
$upload_image = $folder . basename($_FILES["image1"]["name"]);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $upload_image);
```

In this case the file does not have the extension

```
$folder = "uploads/";
$ext = explode('.', basename( $_FILES['image1']['name']));
$upload_image = $folder . basename($_FILES["image1"]["name"].$ext);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image1"]["tmp_name"], $upload_image);
```

The uploads folder is in the same directory that is the php script?

You also can verify if the file was correctly moved doing the following test

```
if (file_exists($upload_image)){
echo "true";
}
```

> Provide a file upload validation before uploading into server it will prevent server from malicious files

How to give file validation in php : [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3535231/php-upload-file-validation)

Comment: Thanks, it does exist in the same directory yes. file_exists returns false :/

Comment: Do you have permission to write in folder uploads?

Comment: Yes @Danielpaiva

Comment: "file does not have the extension" - yes it does. And using the user supplied name means they can deploy any code they like on the server.